# zipped array returns as <zip object at 0x02B6F198>

Tags: arrays, sorting, python-3.x, zip

I have two arrays: `X = [1,2,3,4,5,3,8]` and `Y = ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'C', 'C']`. when i print the zipped array of this, it produces `<zip object at 0x02B6F198>`. The reason these two arrays are zipped is so I can sort `Y` corresponding to `sorted(X)` in the line

`sortedY = [y for x,y in sorted(zip(X,Y))]`

This line of code doesn't sort Y how I would want (`sortedY = ['S','S','C','S','S','S','C']`) but `SortedX` stays in the same arrangement as `X`.

I have a second program in which I use this code and it works fine but this program is significantly smaller in size than the original program.

Comment: What's your logic for sorting?

Comment: What you want `sortedY = ['S','S','C','S','S','S','C']`

Comment: Are you _why_ I want that?

Comment: How is it you want it sorted then? Because that is how Y would be sorted corresponding to X. Also is your question about why you are getting the object method and not a list when you print the zipped lists?

Comment: I do want Y sorted corresponding to X. and yes that is my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are trying to print the zipped lists directly then that won't work. `zip`returns an object and so when you try to print it you just get the object method. If you want to see it as a list, then apply an operation that returns a list.

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,3,8]
Y = ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'C', 'C']

# Some Simple Methods Include
print(list(zip(X, Y)))
print([i for i in zip(X, Y)])

# Output
[(1, 'S'), (2, 'S'), (3, 'S'), (4, 'S'), (5, 'S'), (3, 'C'), (8, 'C')]
```

Now I'm not sure what the issue was though, as what you provided should be working

```
sortedY = [y for x,y in sorted(zip(X,Y))]
print(sortedY)

# Output
['S', 'S', 'C', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'C']
```

As you can see it sorts Y corresponding to sorted X

```
print(sorted(zip(X,Y)))

#Output (X, Y)
[(1, 'S'), (2, 'S'), (3, 'C'), (3, 'S'), (4, 'S'), (5, 'S'), (8, 'C')]
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I'm still unsure of what object method is but I've determined the problem; In an earlier function that was called I used `X.sort()` instead of `something = sorted(X)`